# trying to use yelp api and gather data but map keeps vanishing

Tags: php, html, api, yelp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Yelp Search API Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; font-family: arial;}
        body {margin:0;padding 0;overflow: hidden;}
        #mapContainer {padding-top: 50px;}
        #map, #mapContainer {width:100%; height: 100%;}
        #top {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 100%; height: 50px; line-height: 50px;}
        #spinner { visibility: hidden; margin-left:3px;}
        #poweredby, #searchbox {line-height: 50px;}
        #searchbox {text-align: center;}
        #poweredby { float: right; margin-right: 3px;}
        #poweredby img { vertical-align: baseline;}
        .marker {font-size: 11px;}
        .marker .businessimage { float: left;}
        .marker .ratingsimage {vertical-align:middle; margin-top:0px;}
        .marker .businessinfo { margin-left: 110px;}
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=[AIzaSyByEg0pBD4dGr3gZCk863XZZ0ZBkqhDhR4]"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var YWSID = "aSVpoAZwxvtcwsscdWjBBw"; // common required parameter (api key)

    var map = null;
    var icon = null;

    /*
* Creates the map object and calls setCenterAndBounds
* to instantiate it.
*/
    function load() {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        GEvent.addListener(map, "load", function() {updateMap();});
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40.296448,-79.478141),13);
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);

        if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onresize", function() { map.checkResize()} );
        else if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("resize", function() { map.checkResize()}, false);

        // setup our marker icon
        icon = new GIcon();
        icon.image = "images/marker_star.png";
        icon.shadow = "images/marker_shadow.png";
        icon.iconSize = new GSize(20, 29);
        icon.shadowSize = new GSize(38, 29);
        icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(15, 29);
        icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(15, 3);
    }

    /*
* Construct the URL to call for the API request
*/
    function constructYelpURL() {
        var mapBounds = map.getBounds();
        var URL = "http://api.yelp.com/" +
            "business_review_search?"+
            "callback=" + "handleResults" +
            "&term=" + document.getElementById("term").value +
            "&num_biz_requested=10" +
            "&tl_lat=" + mapBounds.getSouthWest().lat() +
            "&tl_long=" + mapBounds.getSouthWest().lng() +
            "&br_lat=" + mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat() +
            "&br_long=" + mapBounds.getNorthEast().lng() +
            "&ywsid=" + YWSID;
        return encodeURI(URL);
    }

    /*
* Called on the form submission: updates the map by
* placing markers on it at the appropriate places
*/
    function updateMap() {
        // turn on spinner animation
        document.getElementById("spinner").style.visibility = 'visible';

        var yelpRequestURL = constructYelpURL();

        /* clear existing markers */
        map.clearOverlays();

        /* do the api request */
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = yelpRequestURL;
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
        head.appendChild(script);
        return false;
    }

    /*
* If a sucessful API response is received, place
* markers on the map. If not, display an error.
*/
    function handleResults(data) {
        // turn off spinner animation
        document.getElementById("spinner").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        if(data.message.text == "OK") {
            if (data.businesses.length == 0) {
                alert("Error: No businesses were found near that location");
                return;
            }
            for(var i=0; i<data.businesses.length; i++) {
                biz = data.businesses[i];
                createMarker(biz, new GLatLng(biz.latitude, biz.longitude), i);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Error: " + data.message.text);
        }
    }

    /*
* Formats and returns the Info Window HTML
* (displayed in a balloon when a marker is clicked)
*/
    function generateInfoWindowHtml(biz) {
        var text = '<div class="marker">';

        // image and rating
        text += '<img class="businessimage" src="'+biz.photo_url+'"/>';

        // div start
        text += '<div class="businessinfo">';
        // name/url
        text += '<a href="'+biz.url+'" target="_blank">'+biz.name+'</a><br/>';
        // stars
        text += '<img class="ratingsimage" src="'+biz.rating_img_url_small+'"/>&nbsp;based&nbsp;on&nbsp;';
        // reviews
        text += biz.review_count + '&nbsp;reviews<br/><br />';
        // categories
        text += formatCategories(biz.categories);
        // neighborhoods
        if(biz.neighborhoods.length)
            text += formatNeighborhoods(biz.neighborhoods);
        // address
        text += biz.address1 + '<br/>';
        // address2
        if(biz.address2.length)
            text += biz.address2+ '<br/>';
        // city, state and zip
        text += biz.city + ',&nbsp;' + biz.state + '&nbsp;' + biz.zip + '<br/>';
        // phone number
        if(biz.phone.length)
            text += formatPhoneNumber(biz.phone);
        // Read the reviews
        text += '<br/><a href="'+biz.url+'" target="_blank">Read the reviews »</a><br/>';
        // div end
        text += '</div></div>'
        return text;
    }

    /*
* Formats the categories HTML
*/
    function formatCategories(cats) {
        var s = 'Categories: ';
        for(var i=0; i<cats.length; i++) {
            s+= cats[i].name;
            if(i != cats.length-1) s += ', ';
        }
        s += '<br/>';
        return s;
    }

    /*
* Formats the neighborhoods HTML
*/
    function formatNeighborhoods(neighborhoods) {
        s = 'Neighborhoods: ';
        for(var i=0; i<neighborhoods.length; i++) {
            s += '<a href="' + neighborhoods[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + neighborhoods[i].name + '</a>';
            if (i != neighborhoods.length-1) s += ', ';
        }
        s += '<br/>';
        return s;
    }

    /*
* Formats the phone number HTML
*/
    function formatPhoneNumber(num) {
        if(num.length != 10) return '';
        return '(' + num.slice(0,3) + ') ' + num.slice(3,6) + '-' + num.slice(6,10) + '<br/>';
    }

    /*
* Creates a marker for the given business and point
*/
    function createMarker(biz, point, markerNum) {
        var infoWindowHtml = generateInfoWindowHtml(biz)
        var marker = new GMarker(point, icon);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(infoWindowHtml, {maxWidth:400});
        });
        // automatically open first marker
        if (markerNum == 0)
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(infoWindowHtml, {maxWidth:400});
    }

    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="poweredby">Powered by <a href="http://www.yelp.com"><img src="http://static.px.yelp.com/i/map/miniMapLogo.png" border="0" /></a></div>
        <div id="searchbox">
            <form>
                Search for <input type="text" id="term" name="term" value="flannery-cars-greensburg"/> <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="return updateMap();"/>
                <img id="spinner" src="images/spinner.gif" />
                <span class="error" id="errorMessage" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mapContainer"><div id="map"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Website

http://www.724-streamline-marketing.com/testing2.html

I am trying to gather metrics for reviews, rating, map location from the yelp api, I am unsure why it will not stay.

Any help would be grateful or even point me in the right direction on using a 3rd party app to create yelp data

Comment: Please don't post entire pages of code and expect people to wade through all it. Please isolate the problem part and post the minimum example needed to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simple,

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=[AIzaSyByEg0pBD4dGr3gZCk863XZZ0ZBkqhDhR4]"
```

Get rid of the brackets [] surrounding the key.

Comment: kindly explain your answer please in detail.